# jQuery - .append() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of creating a small currency conversion script using the money.js library and have run into a problem with the .append(); part. Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function pfxCurrencyConverter() {
        //get the users options from the form and store in variables
        var pfxFromCurrency = $('#pfx-from-currency').val();
        var pfxToCurrency = $('#pfx-to-currency').val();
        //set base options
        fx.base = pfxFromCurrency
        fx.settings = {
            from: pfxFromCurrency
        };
        //  get the amount input by the user
        var inputAmount = $('#pfx-input-amount').val();

        // Load exchange rates data via the cross-domain/AJAX proxy:
        $.getJSON('http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json', function (data) {
            // Check money.js has finished loading
            if (typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates) {
                fx.rates = data.rates;
                fx.base = data.base;
            } else {
                // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                var fxSetup = {
                    rates: data.rates,
                    base: data.base
                }
            }
            var convertedValue = fx.convert(inputAmount, {to: pfxToCurrency});

            $("#currencies").append("<li>New Value" + convertedValue + "</li>");
        });
    } //end pfxCurrencyConverter
    $(document).ready(function () {
        pfxCurrencyConverter();
    });
</script> 

</head>
<!-- output form for user to populate -->

<!-- Output the front end form, include external stylesheet and define customisable css -->

</head>
<!-- output form for user to populate -->
<body>
<form method="get" onsubmit="return pfxCurrencyConverter();">
Amount: <input type='text' id='pfx-input-amount' /><br />
From: <select id='pfx-from-currency'>
    <option>Please Choose</option>
    <option>GBP</option>
</select><br />
To: <select id='pfx-to-currency'>
    <option>Please Choose</option>
    <option>USD</option>
</select><br />
<input type='submit' value='Convert' />
</form>
<ul id="currencies"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also this in the html right after the submit button, it works fine with just a string but stops working once I add + convertedValue

```
<script>document.write("New Value" + convertedValue);</script>
```

Any help is greatly apprecited

Comment: What is "fx"?  Where is it declared? Also your script tag is inside your "ready" handler.  Is that really what your code looks like? There's no way that would run as it is.

Comment: Also there's no reason to use the CDATA thing in an HTML5 document.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, edited and tidied up but the darn thing still wont .append!

Comment: I call the money.js library which is where the fx is decalred

Comment: Your code *still* has syntax errors.  Can you make sure that the code you've posted here is *really* exactly the same as the code that isn't working?  If it *is* the same, then you should be checking your error console so that you're not missing these fairly obvious errors. (The error is in the object you pass to `fx.convert()` - there's another stray semicolon.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `.append()` was being called before the value was returned from `getJson()`.  Placing the `.append()` inside the `.getJson()` solved the problem.  This works:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://josscrowcroft.github.com/money.js/money.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function ConvertMoney(to, from, amt) {
                // Load exchange rates data via the cross-domain/AJAX proxy:
                $.getJSON('http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json',
                        function (data) {
                            // Check money.js has finished loading:
                            if (typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates) {
                                fx.rates = data.rates;
                                fx.base = data.base;
                            } else {
                                // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                                var fxSetup = {
                                    rates: data.rates,
                                    base: data.base
                                };
                            }

                            var result = "<li>" + fx.convert(amt, { from: from, to: to }) + "</li>";
                            $("#result").append(result);
                        });
            }

            $("#convert").live("click", function () {
                var from = $("#pfx-from-currency").val();
                var to = $("#pfx-to-currency").val();
                var amt = $("#pfx-input-amount").val();

                ConvertMoney(to, from, amt);
            });

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
          var from = $("#pfx-from-currency").val();
                var to = $("#pfx-to-currency").val();
                var amt = $("#pfx-input-amount").val();

                ConvertMoney(to, from, amt);
    }
});

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Amount:
    <input type='text' id='pfx-input-amount' /><br />
    From:
    <select id='pfx-from-currency'>
        <option>Please Choose</option>
        <option>GBP</option>
    </select><br />
    To:
    <select id='pfx-to-currency'>
        <option>Please Choose</option>
        <option>USD</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type='button' id="convert" value='Convert' />
    <ul id="result">
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Matthew, unfortunately changing the class to id didn't seem to have any effect :-(

Comment: Ok.  I also cleaned up some script tags and things so be sure to check all of that.  Also, using the Google Chrome Developer tools is very useful in debugging JavaScript.  It will tell you what error is being thrown.  Same goes for Firebug in Firefox.  Good Luck!

Comment: Many thanks again Matthew, looks much cleaner now, sadly still no append(); - appreciate your help though!

Comment: Matthew, you sir are a legend, just tell me where i can buy you a beer! Thanks so much for your help mate, much appreciated.

Comment: Ha! Not a legend, but thanks.  You just bought me a beer--oatmeal stout.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Matthew, I changed the .append for a .html so to replace the previous result should someone wish to search a different value, I didn't like the way it scrolled down the page! However i would like to have it display the result when enter is pressed aswell as the button is pressed, what did i need to do to make that work please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an object terminated by a semicolon

```
var convertedValue = fx.convert(inputAmount, {to: pfxToCurrency; });
```

that is not valid, try changing it to

```
var convertedValue = fx.convert(inputAmount, {to: pfxToCurrency });
```

Also I would expect

```
var pfxToCurrency = document.getElementById('pfx-to-currency').value
```

and not just

```
var pfxToCurrency = document.getElementById('pfx-to-currency')
```

Comment: Thank you, well spotted, sadly that didn't fix the .append() issue :-(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that properly Closing your `Document ready` function ( ** closing )

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    ........
    .......... 
          });
        } //end pfxCurrencyConverter
    **});**
    $(document).ready(function(){
    pfxCurrencyConverter();
    });
```